# Angular 1.4 UI Router: sub-routes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a site where some pages have a header, content, footer while others might have a different setup. Each "section" of the site has its own module.

---

### Update

Here is a plunker of the current state of things: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/G5CdPPtULVeI1Lfa9Rjg?p=preview

You can see the home state loads, and has 3 views that load a header and footer (from their module folders) and homepage content.  I am trying to add a link to load the next set of views into the original ui-view on the index page to shows the "sample" page with its header, content, and footer views.

---

### Update 2

A plunker with the solution as provided below:
https://plnkr.co/edit/WQHN5ehCDhKo4mkhMbgU?p=preview

---

### Original question:

So I am refactoring my app to have one ui-view at the root that loads a sub-route in each module.  I got this to work with the default route, which loads the "home" module into the main view:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('otherwise', {
  url: '*path',
  template: '',
  controller: function ($state) {
    $state.go('home.page');
  }
});
```

});

And the `home.routes.js` file is like so:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.html',
  abstract: true,
  controller: 'HomeController as home',
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'Home Page'
  }
})
.state('home.page', {
  views: {
    header: {
      templateUrl: 'modules/header/header.html'
     },
    content: {
      templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.content.html'
     },
    footer: {
      templateUrl: 'modules/footer/footer.html'
     }
   }
  });
});
```

It works as expected.  The abstract route loads `home.html`, which is simply my named views:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>
<div ui-view="footer"></div>
```

But I am having a problem linking to a **second** module from the home page.  I created a module "sample" with the exact same setup as above, literally duplicated and renamed the files and routes to "sample" from "home".

On the home.content.html page, I am trying to create a link to the second module "sample" with `a ui-sref="sample">Sample Section</a>` but it errors out "could not transition to the abstract state 'sample'".

I also tried `a ui-sref="sample.page">Sample Section</a>` which does not throw any console errors but goes nowhere.  I thought I had this, but now I am confused.

the routes for sample.routes.js:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('sample', {
  url: '/sample',
  templateUrl: 'modules/sample/sample.html',
  abstract: true,
  controller: 'SampleController as sample',
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'Sample Page'
  }
})
.state('sample.page', {
  views: {
    header: {
      templateUrl: 'modules/header/header.html'
    },
    content: {
      templateUrl: 'modules/sample/sample.content.html'
     },
    footer: {
      templateUrl: 'modules/footer/footer.html'
     }
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: You can't transition to abstract states(your otherwise is what is taking you to home.page).  So the error makes sense. You would have to transition to sample.page.  your setup doesn't really make sense.  I'd sugest moving all of your views (header,content, footer) to the abstract state.

Comment: When I remove "abstract=true" and move the views into the initial state (i.e. "home") I get no errors but a blank page.

Comment: You would have to paste what you have for me to help (or show me a fiddle)

Comment: I have my code above.  I added what I tried based on your suggestion, eliminating the sub-state and moving the views into the abstract state "home".  However, if I trying to go to state "home" I get the error "Cannot transition to abstract state". If I **remove** `abstract='true'` from that state I get a blank screen.

Comment: Also, all the code is at https://github.com/smlombardi/ui-router-test/tree/test2

Comment: Agreed with @nix, you should make a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example is below.

Here we go.  So create a sep landing page (home).  For all the states you want to be in the main part of your app you can use a sep tree called `main`.  If you make your first main state abstract you can technically just have a bunch of child states.

Index page:

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

Views:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modules/main/main.content.html">
  main content
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="modules/footer/footer.html">
  footer
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modules/header/header.html">
  header
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modules/home/home.content.html">
  content
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="modules/home/home.html">
  Nicks {{test}}
  <a ui-sref="main">Test</a>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
         $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    controller: 'HomeController as home',
    templateUrl: 'modules/home/home.html'
    });

  $stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    views: {
      'header@main': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/header/header.html'
      },
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/main/main.html'
      },
      'content@main':{
        templateUrl: 'modules/main/main.content.html'
      },
      'footer@main': {
        templateUrl: 'modules/footer/footer.html'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckh7atmz/1/)

Comment: I had that originally, and it works.  What I am trying to do is create a single view on the index page, and then have the 3 views as you have on the sub pages.  This is because some modules do not have a header and footer, and therefore I can use a single "content" view on those.  I am working on trying to replicate my current state in a plunkr

Comment: Then use a simple home page, and then this type of layout for any other state.

Comment: Here's a working (of the home page only, cannot link to the other modules) plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/G5CdPPtULVeI1Lfa9Rjg?p=preview

Comment: I gave you an example setup that you could use. You asked for a diff type of layout where you could have a home page, so i added a setup that could do it.

Comment: I get what you did, except that my landing page (where you have "Nick's test")  also needs the header and footer view...

Comment: Ok, I simply added the views to the home state.  Bingo.  Thanks.